# PowerShell: Using $env:userprofile in an 'IF' statement

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, shortcut-file

I am using PowerShell ISE (I think 4).

I am writing logon scripts to replace the old '*.BAT' files.

I am trying to test for a user-profile condition before 'creating/deleting' certain directories from the desktop.

#### Example

```
If(($env:userprofile = "rmullins"))
    {
        Remove-Item $env:userprofile\Desktop\ITFILES -Recurse -Force
    }
```

So I run the following to see what's going on:

```
md -Path $env:userprofile\Desktop\ITFILES
```

The path is created in the following location:
C:\Windows\System32.........

The MD command above works fine until I run that 'IF' statement. I think I might not understand how the `$env:userprofile` part works.

Any ideas?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator...

Comment: I think you mean `if ($env:username -eq "rmullins")`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Windows 7:

```
[PS]> echo $ENV:UserProfile
C:\Users\arco444
```

This returns the path to the profile directory. Therefore I'd expect looking only for the username to fail the condition. I'd do a simple match instead:

```
if ($env:userprofile -imatch "rmullins")
{
    Remove-Item $env:userprofile\Desktop\ITFILES -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you so much.
Things that didn't work '==' a comparison operator.

Now that the problem is solved, what is actually taking place with (($env:userprofile = rmullins))  Am I actually changing my user-profile?  Whatever is going on, when I run commands like, 'md %userprofile%/desktop'  a path gets created with %userprofile% (percentages and all)....

Thanks again folks for the help.

Comment: @banditFox The assignment operator means that your are changing the value of the $env:userprofile variable in that specific PowerShell session (it does not have any effect on other PowerShell sessions or anything else on the rest of the OS). `==` is not a comparison operator either, in PowerShell. The PowerShell comparison operator for equals is `-eq`. I suggest you run the PowerShell command `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` to learn more about the comparison operators in PowerShell.

Comment: Why are you not using `$env:username` instead? Would be much more precise.

Comment: As Luxs pointed out, you correctly mention the username but in the code you use userprofile to compare with a username - which always fails. So my advice is to correct it to `$env:username` instead of `$env:userprofile`. And your answer is not only valid for `windows 7` but for recent versions of powershell.

Comment: like @Timo said `Write-Output ("$env:userprofile\Desktop" -eq "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop")`